# Date/Time picker phone and/or OS default in Android

Tags: android, dialog, datepicker, timepicker

In my android app I have this datepicker and timepicker.
Some phones have a spinning wheel as their default date/time picker.
I would like them to look like a spinning wheel when that's
the default picker for the phone. My app minimally supports Android 2.1
and because of that, all the datepickers and timepickers look like just
a dialogbox with a edittext field, a + button and a - button [(example)](https://datetimepicker.googlecode.com/files/datetimepicker.png) .
I would like to go for a third party solution if that's the only option.
Isn't there a way (for example in xml), to define the date and time picker
as phone default?
Kind regards,
Fabian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've used

http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/

in the past, the code is written very readable, so you can modify it to your needs.
it supports:
+ view recycling
+ cyclic/circular/infinite looping
+ comparatively fast even when the wheel is huge (other solutions aren't)
+ custom views

drawbacks:
- last update march 2011
- skinning has to be done in the library project

If you want to stick to the ICS default datepicker consider 
https://github.com/SimonVT/android-datepicker
which is a backport of the original ICS datepicker (he also backported the numberpicker).
However i found it to be on the slow side if you size it up.

---

P.S. these are not my projects, props to
- Yuri Kankan (android wheel)
- Simon Vig Therkildsen (backported ICS numberpicker)

Comment: Thank you for those handy links. Maybe I will go with the android wheel. But is it just impossible to define something in xml styles tags? I've got the feeling it's easier than I think. Anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: no, the background and shadow stuff is more or less hardcoded.
you can swap the drawables in the drawable folder,
for the rest you should check WheelView.java (remove the shadow etc...) the code is really very readable, you'll find what you need with ease.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/). This android wheel provides iPhone like lists. There are samples available to create date and time picker using this.